# Why was my question on the attributes of OpenAI models closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I'm a bit scared to ask, but: can anyone help me understand why my question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/77616944/781723) was closed?  Do you have any feedback how to make this more suitable for Stack Overflow and useful for other site visitors?  Or is the topic simply not appropriate here?  Or something else?  Are there some lessons I should learn?

I am fine if the answer is that the question is simply not suitable here and should remain closed.  I accept the decision of the community.  I am looking to learn from the experience and grateful for whatever you can teach me, so that I can contribute better in the future.

---

The close reason indicates "We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations.", yet the question doesn't seek recommendations, it asks for factual information about the attributes of various models available via the OpenAI.  It can be (and is) answered with facts and citations.  So I don't find the close reason helpful.  But I understand that the close reason is only a summary and there are many norms and expectations that go beyond what can fit in a close reason.  And I do understand that [reviewers don't always pick exactly the right close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413260/781723), so I recognize it might not be helpful to focus too much on the specific close reason.

I had the impression that this question fits within the scope of Stack Overflow, namely, serving as a knowledge base of technical information that will be useful to programmers, in the form of high-quality questions and answers.  I had thought that my question fits within this mission and might be useful to others, and it took me a non-trivial amount of research to identify the answer, so I posted it in an attempt to help others who might have a similar question.  I'm sure I'm missing something, but it's not obvious to me why the question is unsuitable, and I'm struggling to understand how I should adjust my mental model.

Comment: Your question is not really about programming, its about LLM properties, not useful for programmers actually. And it does sound a lot like asking for recommendations...

Comment: Your question wasn’t a programming question. There wasn’t a single line of code provided nor was there a MRE. In fact your question is asking for a LLM recommendation. The closest close reason would be a closure dor asking for a product recommendation. At this time no Stack Exchange community is allowing questions seeking a LLM recommendation

Comment: *"And it does sound a lot like asking for recommendations..."* - uh, recommendations of *what*, exactly, @Dr.Snoopy? It's a strictly factual question; I don't see how to interpret it as seeking recommendations.

Comment: @MarkAmery - “Which, if any, of the OpenAI models that are available for fine-tuning have been instruction tuned?” - That’s asking for a recommendation.

Comment: @SecurityHound No, it's asking a factual question about an already-specified set of models. Just because the answer could influence what model someone uses doesn't make it a "recommendation" question - otherwise every question about how some tool behaves or whether a library has certain functionality would be a recommendation question too.

Comment: I am also dubious of the proposition that this question doesn't relate to "programming". In what non-programming context would this information ever be useful? I am not an expert on OpenAI's models and APIs but it doesn't look to me like there's any possible way to use any of these models without writing code to do it.

Comment: @SecurityHound, I appreciate the feedback.  Perhaps I have a different interpretation of SO rules.  In the interest of learning, I will share my perspective, and you can teach me about anything I might be missing.  1) I wonder whether you are aware that code/MRE is not required for SO questions.  Code/MRE is required for questions that seek debugging help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334894/781723.  I was not seeking debugging.

Comment: 2) Nowhere did I ask for a recommendation.  Asking a factual question is not asking for a recommendation.  It might be worth remembering why recommendation questions are banned: it is because they "[tend to attract opinionated answers and spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and because "[technology moves so rapidly](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)"  that answers will rapidly become obsolete.  I don't think those apply here.

Comment: That said, I accept the feedback that the question does not appear to be a programming question, or the connection to programming is not sufficiently clear.  Yes, it's true, I was looking to use fine-tuning through the OpenAI API, and it might be true that the only way to fine-tune these models is via the API (I'm not aware of any other way).  But I accept that this might not be enough to make it on-topic.  Thanks again for the feedback, everyone, this helps me understand better the scope of SO and what questions might (not) be appropriate here.

Comment: @MarkAmery Three SO users interpreted that way, I am not the only one.

Comment: @MarkAmery "In what non-programming context would this information ever be useful?" In Machine Learning and LLM research, LLMs are not a programming tool (yet).

Comment: This is akin to asking "Which methods of a javascript array have an index argument?", which wouldn't be a recommendation question but would be similarly... not all that interesting.

Comment: @KevinB, Thanks for letting me know.  I don't see that as analogous, but I recognize that what's interesting is a matter of taste.  Would you recommend I add more motivation for how the answer is useful?  Also I wonder if I might share a possible counterpoint for your consideration.  I would not recommend closing a question that is not all that interesting as "seeking recommendations for books, tools, ...".  I found it confusing to encounter such a close reason on this question.  I thought that normally the remedy for questions that are "not that interesting" is a bit different.

Comment: @D.W. - I find any question about LLM to be unhelpful, but you wanted to be told, which LLM fit your requirements. Likewise, training a LLM, isn’t and doesn’t require programming knowledge. Question would have been closed on December 15th but something cause the close vote to be invalidated. It stayed open 3 months longer then it probably would have if that didn’t happen

Comment: @SecurityHound, makes sense!  Thank you for taking the time to help me understand better!

Comment: (One of those CV's was mine.) Yeah... sorry. I just saw the link labelled "OpenAI models..." and thought it was just looking for a recommendation. Is the question on-topic as a programming question? If so, I could be convinced to re-open it.

Comment: Bit of a discrepancy here. This question: *"a knowledge base of technical information that will be **useful to programmers**"* vs. the tour: *"a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question **about programming**"* (emphasis added). According to the tour, on-topic does not cover everything that will be useful to programmers (nor even all of computer science), but just things specifically about programming.

Answer (score 32):

Fine-tuning LLMs is not a programming matter, first and foremost, so the question is inherently off-topic.

Second, your question is asking for a list of things to be presented to you. List questions are historically [off-topic on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic) as they are a form of tool recommendation requests, which are categorically off-topic. While in your case there might be a finite list, the request is still *implicitly* a tool recommendation request, because the purpose is to find a tool suitable for use for some task.

Another site on our network (Software Recommendations, GenAI, or *maybe* Cross Validated) may specifically allow this type of question, but it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The [AI.SE] site would be a natural fit as well I think.

Comment: You have to write code to finetune but it is not programming?

Comment: you *don't* have to write code to finetune. you just have to come up with the dataset, then run the program. this question wasn't about how to finetune though, it was about which OpenAI models have a certain property. that's *not* a programming question, that's browsing published materials for the facts (literature review) or badgering their support.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks, that one surprisingly didn't come up in the site list for me when I searched for AI, or at least it wasn't anywhere near the top 5-10 suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

After reading this more closely, I don't think that this is a recommendation question. You're asking which models from a pre-defined list have a specific characteristic, which is purely a factual question. That being said, an opinionated answer on which model you should use or a spam answer recommending a model that's not on the list wouldn't answer the question.
 
That being said, as others have indicated, this is *arguably* off-topic for not being about programming. Even this is a somewhat debatable point, though, because as others have indicated, I don't see how this could possibly be useful in a non-programming context.

Either way, this question *may* be a better fit for GenAI Stack Exchange.